# Hibernate: WrongClassException

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a problem with hibernate. I have a superclass "Person" and two subclasses "Client" and Trainer. This is the code:

Person:

```
@Table(name = "Person")
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person implements Serializable{

    protected IntegerProperty personID;
    protected ObjectProperty<String> foreName;
    protected ObjectProperty<String> sureName;
    protected ObjectProperty<Date> birthdate;

    public Person(int personID, String forName, String sureName, Date birthdate){
        this.personID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(personID);
        this.foreName = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(forName);
        this.sureName = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(sureName);
        this.birthdate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(birthdate);
    }

    public  Person(){
        this(0,null, null, null);
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PersonID")
    public int getPersonID() {
        return personID.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty personIDProperty() {
        return personID;
    }

    public void setPersonID(int personID) {
        this.personID.set(personID);
    }

    @Column (name="forname")
    public String getForeName() {
        return foreName.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<String> foreNameProperty() {
        return foreName;
    }

    public void setForeName(String foreName) {
        this.foreName.set(foreName);
    }

    @Column (name="surename")
    public String getSureName() {
        return sureName.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<String> sureNameProperty() {
        return sureName;
    }

    public void setSureName(String sureName) {
        this.sureName.set(sureName);
    }

    @Column (name="birthdate")
    public Date getBirthdate() {
        return birthdate.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Date> birthdateProperty() {
        return birthdate;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(Date birthdate) {
        this.birthdate.set(birthdate);
    }

    @Transient
    public ObjectProperty<String> getFullName (){
        return new SimpleObjectProperty<String>(getForeName() + " " + getSureName());
    }
}
```

Client

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Client")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="PersonID")
public class Client extends Person implements Serializable{


    private List<TrainingGoal> trainingGoals;

    public Client(String forName, String sureName, Date birthdate) {
        super(0, forName, sureName, birthdate);
    }

    public Client() {
        super();
    }


    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name="ClientTrainingGoals",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PersonID ")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="TrainingGoalID")})
    public List<TrainingGoal> getTrainingGoals() {
        return trainingGoals;
    }

    public void setTrainingGoals(List<TrainingGoal> trainingGoals) {
        this.trainingGoals = trainingGoals;
    }
}
```

Trainer

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Trainer")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="PersonID")
public class Trainer extends Person implements Serializable {

    public Trainer(String forName, String sureName, Date birthdate) {
        super(0, forName, sureName, birthdate);
    }

    public Trainer() {
        super();
    }


}
```

I use this to call/get the Objects:

```
trainers = db.getAll(Trainer.class);
clients = db.getAll(Client.class);
```

And the DB method would be:

```
public ObservableList getAll(Class c) {


    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(c);
    ObservableList data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    data.addAll(criteria.list());
    //session.close();

    return data;
}
```

This is the full error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2/2108649164.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at gui.main.MainFrameController.<init>(MainFrameController.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:923)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:967)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:216)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2711)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2445)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2413)
    at gui.main.MainApp.initRootLayout(MainApp.java:50)
    at gui.main.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:40)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/1797966936.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/547246464.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$51/1960844796.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$50/2127579855.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=10] was not of the specified subclass [beans.Client] : loaded object was of wrong class class beans.Trainer
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceAlreadyLoaded(Loader.java:1551)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1504)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:726)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1718)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
    at db.Database.getAll(Database.java:69)
    at bl.BackendBl.<init>(BackendBl.java:52)
    at bl.BackendBl.<clinit>(BackendBl.java:13)
    ... 27 more
```

This is the hibernate sql output, maybe it helps, but it looks good to me

```
Hibernate: select this_.PersonID as PersonID1_7_0_, this_1_.birthdate as birthdat2_7_0_, this_1_.forname as forname3_7_0_, this_1_.surename as surename4_7_0_ from Trainer this_ inner join Person this_1_ on this_.PersonID=this_1_.PersonID
Hibernate: select this_.PersonID as PersonID1_7_0_, this_1_.birthdate as birthdat2_7_0_, this_1_.forname as forname3_7_0_, this_1_.surename as surename4_7_0_ from Client this_ inner join Person this_1_ on this_.PersonID=this_1_.PersonID
```

As suggested in another thread, I tried adding @org.hibernate.annotations.DiscriminatorOptions(force=true) 
to the superclass, but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: My guess is that you have a person in the database that is both a Trainer and a Client: i.e. the same personId is in both tables.

Comment: Is that a problem? Because that is exactly what I want. I want a Person to be either a Client or Trainer but a Client could also be a Trainer

Comment: Of course it's a problem. Java doesn't have multiple inheritance. An object can't be both of type Trainer and of type Client. And Hibernate will never allow two different instances of the same Person entity. You should use associations rather than inheritance: A Person **has a** ClientRole, and/or **has a** TrainerRole. The tables stay identical. But the entities need to change.

Comment: Ah ok. Can I still have two different Objects? Because I don't want to change all the code actually to just use the Person object...

Comment: Let's assume it was possible. `Trainer t = findTrainer(id); Client c = findClient(id); t.setSureName("foo"); c.setSureName("bar"); Person p = findPerson(id); em.remove(p);` What should `p` be initialized to? t or c? When the transaction commits, what should Hibernate store in the surename column? "foo" or "bar"? What should Hibernate delete? The whole person, only the trainer row, or only the client row?

Comment: Ah ok, I get it now. Haven't thought about the p = findPerson... problem because I never intended to use it that way... Thanks